# Command prompt doesn't appear on Ease of access option at logon screen after trying to reset Windows Server 2012 Administrator password

Tags: windows-server-2012, reset-password

- OS: Windows Server 2012
- Version: R2

Hi everyone!

After trying to access command prompt to complete the resetting password process with installation disk Windows Server 2012 Administrator user, the only options that appear on Ease of access are:

- Narrator
- Magnifier
- On-Screen Keyboard
- High Contrast (Off/On)
- Sticky Keys (Off/On)
- Filter Keys (Off/On)

NOTE: Also, I don't find the utilman.exe file before and after the mentioned process. (Is it being deleted automatically?)

How can I solve it and finally reset Administrator password?

Regards and waiting,
Alan

I'm trying to reset Admin. password, but until now I'm not getting it.